# Disable delete user

Tags: users, hooks

My site has custom post type 'Portfolio'. If a user has at least one Portfolio, how can I disable the option to delete that user?

I found the action/hook `delete_user`, but it doesn't seem right for this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand your problem and/or your question. Please clarify your problem. This might help: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on "delete", the action 'delete_user'  will be launched: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-admin/includes/user.php#L313

After that you can check, if the user has written at least one 'portfolio' post.

```
add_action('delete_user', 'sw_portfolio_check');

function sw_portfolio_check( $user_id ) {
    $result = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'author'=>$user_id,
                    'post_type'=>'portfolio',
                    'posts_per_page'=>1,
                )
            );
    if ( count($result->posts) !== 0 ){
        wp_die("User has a portfolio and can't be deleted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to *disable the option to delete*, If you mean the delete button on the user list at `/wp-admin/users.php` you can use *user_row_actions* class to hide the 'delete' link with below snippet:

```
add_filter(
  'user_row_actions',
  function($actions, $user_object) {
    $result = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'author'=> $user_object->ID,
                    'post_type'=>'portfolio',
                    'posts_per_page'=>1,
                )
            );
    if ( count($result->posts) !== 0 ){
      unset($actions['delete']);
    }
    return $actions;
  },
  1,2
);
```

The above snippet just hides the link. It does not prevent access to the delete screen. To do that, we'll need more code:

```
add_action(
  'load-users.php',
  function() {
    if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
      $user_object = get_userdata($_GET['user']);
          $result = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'author'=> $user_object->ID,
                            'post_type'=>'portfolio',
                            'posts_per_page'=>1,
                        )
                    );
        if( count($result->posts) !== 0 ){
        wp_die('This user cannot be deleted');
        }
    }
  }  
);
```

Hope this help you well!